# running pip install from python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I have a CentOS server (5.6) which has Python 2.4.3 on it. I have another local installation of Python (2.7.5) installed in `/opt` and soft-links created as follows `/usr/local/bin/python2.7` and `/usr/local/python2.7`. I want to install python-requests using `pip`. While installing using the command `pip install requests`, I get the following error:

```
root ~/ff_test_ff # pip install requests
Unpacking ./requests
  Running setup.py egg_info for package from file:///root/ff_test_ff/requests
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 14, in ?
      File "/tmp/pip-MM685m-build/setup.py", line 6, in ?
        import requests
      File "requests/__init__.py", line 58
        from . import utils
             ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 14, in ?

  File "/tmp/pip-MM685m-build/setup.py", line 6, in ?

    import requests

  File "requests/__init__.py", line 58

    from . import utils

         ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

I'm assuming it's still trying to use Python 2.4. I [checked here](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/351) which says 2.4 isn't supported. So how do I run the `pip install` command but use python2.7 instead?

Answer (score 0):

you need to set the `PYTHONPATH` / `PYTHONHOME` [like here](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html)

you can also try to install [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv)

Answer (score 0):

You probably should (re)install a new version of pip explicitly for the new Python version. On [pip installation instructions page](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html) it says that

> pip works with CPython versions 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, 3.3 and also pypy.

While installing, be sure to use the newer version of Python instead of the old one.